# Dynamically add rtmp source to running pipeline using compositor

Tags: rust, gstreamer

I have a very simple Gstreamer pipeline looking like this

`uridecodebin -> compositor -> videoconvert -> autovideosink`

I want to be able at any time to add a new `uridecodebin` on the compositor.
If I add the second source before the pipeline is running, it works fine, but if I delay the addition of the second source, pipeline gets stuck and I have tons of QoS events telling me frames are being dropped.

This issue does not occur if I only read non-live sources, but it happens with my RTMP streams, or if I mix live and non-live sources.

When `sync=false` is set on the sync, RTMP streams are played, but it does not work with non-live sources.

My assumption is that I am missing a step with time/clock/latency, but I don't know what.

Here is the code (in rust) used to add a new source :

```rust
fn connect_pad_added(src_pad: &gst::Pad, src: &gst::Element, compositor: &gst::Element) {
    println!("Received new pad {} from {}", src_pad.name(), src.name());

    let new_pad_caps = src_pad
        .current_caps()
        .expect("Failed to get caps of new pad.");
    let new_pad_struct = new_pad_caps
        .structure(0)
        .expect("Failed to get first structure of caps.");
    let new_pad_type = new_pad_struct.name();

    let is_video = new_pad_type.starts_with("video/x-raw");
    if !is_video {
        println!(
            "It has type {} which is not raw video. Ignoring.",
            new_pad_type
        );
        return;
    }

    println!("Created template");
    let sink_pad = compositor
        .request_pad_simple("sink_%u")
        .expect("Could not get sink pad from compositor");

    println!("Got pad");

    if sink_pad.is_linked() {
        println!("We are already linked. Ignoring.");
        return;
    }

    if sink_pad.name() == "sink_0" {
        sink_pad.set_property("width", 1920i32);
        sink_pad.set_property("height", 1080i32);
    } else {
        sink_pad.set_property("alpha", 0.8f64);
    }

    let res = src_pad.link(&sink_pad);
    if res.is_err() {
        println!("Type is {} but link failed.", new_pad_type);
    } else {
        println!("Link succeeded (type {}).", new_pad_type);
    }

}

fn add_new_element(pipeline: &gst::Pipeline, uri: &str) {
    println!("Adding new element");
    let source = gst::ElementFactory::make("uridecodebin")
        .property("uri", uri)
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let compositor = pipeline.by_name("compositor").unwrap();
    pipeline.add(&source).unwrap();
    source.connect_pad_added(move |src, src_pad| {
        println!("Received new pad {} from {}", src_pad.name(), src.name());
        connect_pad_added(src_pad, src, &compositor);
    });

    source
        .set_state(gst::State::Paused)
        .expect("Unable to set the uridecodebin to the `Paused` state");

    println!("Added new element");
}
```